# Sourcetree with Bitbucket Error: fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly

Tags: git, sourcetree

I'm using Sourcetree but am unable to push a commit as I've been getting this error.

I'd appreciate any help on fixing this.

Answer (score 2):

For example, your repo is blue_repo, type

```
cd blue_repo
```

to change directory to your git repository correctly.

Then you maybe do more this task:

```
git remote add origin https://your_user_name@bitbucket.org/owner_account/project_name.git
```

For example:

```
git remote add origin https://dovanvy@bitbucket.org/dovanvy/dovanvy.git
```

And, you also should increment buffer size, for example:

```
git config --global http.postBuffer 524288000
```

Comment: It seems that the origin already exists as I get this error: fatal: remote origin already exists.

Comment: Ok, for example, your repo is **blue_repo**, type `cd blue_repo`, to chance directory to your git repository correctly.

Comment: I'm now getting:  No such file or directory. It doesn't seem to recognize the repository name.

Comment: Your working folder isn't a git local repository. A git local repository (folder/directory) must have `.git` folder inside it.